# jQuery Mobile How to simulate data-rel="dialog"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-mobile, razor, dialog

Is there a way to simulate the *data-rel="dialog"* attribute to show a page as a dialog page?
I can't use this one because I use the button for the LogIn/LogOut model, and this one doesn't work if I don't insert the *data-ajax="false"* attribute.
But using this I cannot use the ajax-based data-rel attribute.

So I need a trick to create a dialog page without using the dialog attribute on the anchor link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully in the next iteration of jQM  ( 1.2 ) you could use the Popup, You can currently test this out in the pre-release builds:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html

[image]

or a form login

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using Popups, but I have a full LogOn page in Asp.Net MVC3 to render, and it is quite impossible to do with popups.

Comment: @Jack88PD added a form login popup, would something like this work?

Comment: It actually works. Not good to see (cause using Asp.Net MVC I have to add a lot of lines to the popup body (and I don't keep separated different controllers), but it works. Thanks!